# Favorites in Finder Sidebar

Tags: macos

Having installed Mountain Lion 10.8.3 I can not get the sidebar in Finder to display Favorites.

Finder > Preferences > Sidebar shows a number of boxes against Favorite folders, but these can not be selected

Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem resolved by a restart following some updates from the App store

Comment: Please accept the answer below rather than leaving a comment on the question so others can easily spot the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was a known bug which has already been fixed by Apple. By running **Software Update** on your Mac you'll be good to go!